# Path based routing issues Traefik as Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I'm running through what looks like a configuration issue! I am using traefik as ingress controller within kubernetes and I have an ingress to route some URLs to route some frontends to various backends. Let's say I have something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: ReplacePathRegex
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/authservice/(.*) /$1
        backend:
          serviceName: auth
          servicePort: 8901
      - path: /api/svcXXX/v1/files/cover/(.*) /v1/files/cover/$1
        backend:
          serviceName: files
          servicePort: 8183
      - path: /api/svcXXX/v1/files/image/(.*) /v1/files/image/$1
        backend:
          serviceName: files
          servicePort: 8183
```

Using Postman (or any other client), if I POST a request on `http://foo.io/api/authservice/auth/oauth/token`, while looking in the access logs, it seems that it is routed to `http://foo.io/api/svcXXX/v1/files/image/(.*) /v1/files/image/$1`. I'm seeing this in the access logs:

`[03/Jul/2018:12:57:17 +0000] "POST /api/authservice/auth/oauth/token HTTP/1.1" 401 102 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.5" 15 "foo.io/api/svcXXX/v1/files/image/(.*) /v1/files/image/$1" 37ms`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** since the documentation is changed, I've updated the links, but content on the documentation pages would be different.

`ReplacePathRegex` is a  **modifier** rule. According to [documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#modifiers):

> Modifier rules only modify the request. They do not have any impact on routing decisions being made.
>
> Following is the list of existing modifier rules:
>
> - `AddPrefix`: `/products`: Add path prefix to the existing request path prior to forwarding the request to the backend.
> - `ReplacePath`: `/serverless-path`: Replaces the path and adds the old path to the X-Replaced-Path header. Useful for mapping to AWS Lambda or Google Cloud Functions.
> - `ReplacePathRegex`: `^/api/v2/(.*) /api/$1`: Replaces the path with a regular expression and adds the old path to the X-Replaced-Path header. Separate the regular expression and the replacement by a space.

To route requests, you should use [**matchers**](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#matchers):

> Matcher rules determine if a particular request should be forwarded to a backend.
>
> Separate multiple rule values by , (comma) in order to enable ANY semantics (i.e., forward a request if any rule matches). Does not work for Headers and HeadersRegexp.
>
> Separate multiple rule values by ; (semicolon) in order to enable ALL semantics (i.e., forward a request if all rules match).
>
> ###Path Matcher Usage Guidelines
> This section explains when to use the various path matchers.
>
> Use `Path` if your backend listens on the exact path only. For instance,
> `Path: /products` would match `/products` but not `/products/shoes`.
>
> Use a `*Prefix*` matcher if your backend listens on a particular base
> path but also serves requests on sub-paths. For instance, `PathPrefix: /products` would match `/products` but also `/products/shoes` and
> `/products/shirts`. Since the path is forwarded as-is, your backend is
> expected to listen on /products.
>
> Use a `*Strip` matcher if your backend listens on the root path (/) but
> should be routable on a specific prefix. For instance,
> `PathPrefixStrip: /products` would match `/products` but also
> /`products/shoes` and `/products/shirts`. Since the path is stripped prior
> to forwarding, your backend is expected to listen on `/`. If your
> backend is serving assets (e.g., images or Javascript files), chances
> are it must return properly constructed relative URLs. Continuing on
> the example, the backend should return `/products/shoes/image.png` (and
> not `/images.png` which Traefik would likely not be able to associate
> with the same backend). The `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header (available since
> Traefik 1.3) can be queried to build such URLs dynamically.
>
> Instead of distinguishing your backends by path only, you can add a
> Host matcher to the mix. That way, namespacing of your backends
> happens on the basis of hosts in addition to paths.

Full list of matchers and their descriptions can be found [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/overview/)

Comment: it should be noted that in `2.6` these annotations are not supported. note that your last link goes to middleware, which not all want or care about. _plain_ ingress does not support such functionality in traefik.