# Configure Kubernetes Traefik Ingress with different path rewrites for each service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I'm in the process of migration of our application from single instance Docker-compose configuration to Kubernetes. I currently have the following example NGINX configuration, running as a reverse proxy of my application:

```
server {
  server_name             example.com;
  ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/${CERT_NAME};
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/${KEY_NAME};

  listen                  443 ssl;
  keepalive_timeout       70;

  access_log              /var/log/nginx/access.log mtail;

  ssl_protocols           xxxxxx
  ssl_ciphers             xxxxxx
  ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout     10m;

  rewrite_log             on;
  resolver                127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

  location /push/ {
        auth_basic                    "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file          /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
        rewrite /push/(.*)        /index.php/$1 break;
        proxy_pass                    pushinterface:3080;
  }

  location /flights/ {
        rewrite /flights/(.*)         /$1 break;
        proxy_pass                    flightstats:3090;
  }

  location /api/ {
        proxy_pass                    $api;
  }

  location /grafana/ {
        access_log                    off;
        log_not_found                 off;
        proxy_pass                    http://grafana:3000;
        rewrite ^/grafana/(.*)        /$1 break;
  }
```

}

My initial plans for the reverse proxy part was implementing an ingress with NGINX ingress controller, but I saw that my configuration can be created as Ingress only with NGINX Plus. That's why I decided to try with Traefik, but I'm not sure if it's still possible to have different rewrites of the path for each service.

I tried the following Ingress configuration, but it seems it's not working:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-traefik 
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: ReplacePathRegex
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: pushinterface
          servicePort: 80
        path: /push/(.*) /index/$1
      - backend:
          serviceName: flights
          servicePort: 80
        path: /flights/(.*) /$1
       - backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
      - backend:
          serviceName: grafana
          servicePort: 80
        path: /grafana/(.*) /$1
```

I will appreciate any help for solving this task

Comment: Do you try it on the cloud ? On premise ? When you run kubectl get svc do you see all the services ? please remove the host in the rules and try again. please share more info

Comment: I'm configuring it on premise. All the services are available with kubectl get svc. It's interesting that always the first service in the configuration list is routed correctly, but for the other ones which must have rewritten path i get 404. And when I access http://example.com I also get the first mentioned service. I tried also without the host in the rules and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of unsuccessful attempts to solve my issue, I did it with Nginx ingress controller and it works great! Here's the ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite /push/(.*) /index/$1 break;
      rewrite /flights/(.*) /$1 break;
      rewrite /grafana/(.*) /$1 break;

spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: pushinterface
          servicePort: 80
        path: /push
      - backend:
          serviceName: flights
          servicePort: 80
        path: /flights
       - backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
      - backend:
          serviceName: grafana
          servicePort: 80
        path: /grafana
```

Thanks to everyone for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplacePathRegex` rule type in your example does not guarantee that incoming requests will be forwarded to the target backends, as mentioned in Traefik [Documentation](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/basics.md#frontends).

In order to route requests to the endpoints, use [Matcher](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/basics.md#matchers) instead of `Modifiers` rules, as they are designed for that purpose.

Find a separate discussion on the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156406/path-based-routing-issues-traefik-as-ingress-controller).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you provide some code example for the Ingress, because I cannot find a proper example for using the Matchers in Ingresses?

Comment: Check this [link](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) and refer to Path-based routing example.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this example is very basic and doesn't cover my use case. I mean not every path of the services in the ingress should be changed. The ingress, which I provided is just an example and I have more services. I can easily change the most of their paths to satisfy a basic ingress config, but some of the services are third party and I cannot change their paths. That's why I was looking for more advanced Ingress configuration

Comment: Get your self familiar with a Matchers rules usage [Guidelines](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/basics.md#path-matcher-usage-guidelines) in order to find best solution suitable for your relevant cases.